# Ansible Customizing a local log file that contains multiple tasks outputs from a playbook

Tags: logging, ansible

In my playbook I have two major tasks one task that change the gateway last digit for Debian machines and the second one applies to Redhat machines everything works fine but to be able to trace the machines on which the tasks were executed succesfully on a local file (kind of a log).

I tried to register the results of both tasks with a register

for Debian :

```yaml
 name: change default gateway address
      replace:
        path: /etc/network/interfaces
        regexp: '(up route add default gw [\d]*\.[\d]*.[\d]*)\.[\d]*$'
        replace: '\1.254'
        backup: yes
      when: (ansible_facts['distribution'] == "Debian")
      register: debresult
```

for Redhat:

```yaml
- name: change default gateway address on Redhat
      replace:
        path: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
        regexp: '(GATEWAY=[\d]*\.[\d]*.[\d]*)\.[\d]*$'
        replace: '\1.254'
        backup: yes
      when: (ansible_facts['distribution'] == "RedHat")
      register: redresult
```

and then I added a task to log the changed hosts :

```yaml
    - name: log the changed hosts
      local_action:
        module : copy
        content: "{{ansible_facts.hostname}}{{debresult}}"
        content: "{{ansible_facts.hostname}}{{redresult}}"
        dest: /tmp/changed.txt
```

What I am trying to have is a log like this :

```
debianhostname {"msg": "", "success": true, "changed": true}
redhathostname {"msg": "", "success": true, "changed": true}
```

But the problem is that I only get the last output so how can have both entries in my file? is there a module that I can use ? I have tried the local_action with copy, set_fact but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

here's the answer using a max of ansible modules :

```yaml
 - name: log the changed hosts
      local_action:
        module : lineinfile
        line: "{{ ansible_facts['hostname'] }} {{item}}"
        dest: /tmp/changed.txt
      with_items:
        - "{{debresult}}"
        - "{{redresult}}"
```